# SHA1 JavaScript Implementation for large string

Tags: javascript, hash, sha1

I have the same problem as :[Can SHA-1 algorithm be computed on a stream? With low memory footprint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495994/can-sha-1-algorithm-be-computed-on-a-stream-with-low-memory-footprint)

I'm looking for a JavaScript implementation which computed block by block of a very large string. The idea is to slice the string into 512 bits block and do it block by block.

Any hint?

[updated]
Thanks sunetos's help, I write a litte html5 java script app: [Generate SHA1 File Checksum Using HTML5 File API in Javascript](http://www.ke-cai.net/2010/07/generate-sha1-file-checksum-using-html5.html)

Comment: link broken, working fiddle in the comment from user unsynchronized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I came across one by Paul Johnston at http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/contrib/sha1_stream.js . It is listed on the page http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/scripts.html . I have not tested it myself, but I have used his non-streamable version that he modified for it.

UPDATE: Here is some example code (I verified it against a separate SHA1 known to be correct). Make sure you include the original sha1.js (found at http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha1.js) before the streamable sha1_stream.js.

```
<script src="sha1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="sha1_stream.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var input = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    var blocksize = 512;
    var h = naked_sha1_head();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += blocksize) {
        var len = Math.min(blocksize, input.length - i);
        var block = input.substr(i, len);
        naked_sha1(str2binb(block), len*chrsz, h);
    }
    var result = binb2hex(naked_sha1_tail(h));

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks sunetos.
I guess this is what I want. But there is no document nor example to show how to use it.  Can you help me?

Comment: Note that the current version of the sha1_stream.js has a bug and will give incorrect results for certain input lengths. To fix this replace `h[8] += 512 - len % 512;` with `h[8] = (len + 576 >> 9) << 9;` - it forgets to include the padding when rounding to a multiple of 512 bits. The non-streaming version doesn't have that bug.

Comment: here's a jsfiddle based on this answer:http://jsfiddle.net/ndJ2x/9/embedded/result source is here http://jsfiddle.net/ndJ2x/9