# How to check if two large files are identical on amazon S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, large-files, multipart, boto

I need to move large files (>5GB) on amazon S3 with boto, from and to the same bucket. For this I need to use the multipart API, which does not use md5 sums for etags.

While I think (well only 98% sure) that my code is correct, I would like to verify that the new copy is not corrupted before deleting the original. However I could not find any method except downloading both objects and comparing them locally, which for 5GB+ files is quite a long process.

For the record, below is my code to copy a large file with boto, maybe this can help someone. If there is no good solution to my problem maybe someone will find a bug and prevent me from corrupting data.

```
import boto

copy_size = 1000000000  #1e9
bucket_name = 'mybucket'
orig_key_name = 'ABigFile'
dest_key_name = 'ABigFile.clone'

s3 = boto.connect_s3()
mybucket = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name)

key = mybucket.get_key(orig_key_name)

mp = mybucket.initiate_multipart_upload(dest_key_name)  #keyname

print 'key size: ', key.size

count = 1 
start = 0
end = -1

while end < key.size-1:
   print 'count: ', count
   start = end + 1 
   end = min( key.size -1 , start + copy_size )
   mp.copy_part_from_key(bucket_name, orig_key_name, count , start, end )
   count+=1

mp.complete_upload()
```

This code only works for original key sizes >= 5368709121 bytes.

Comment: Test with two small ~1kB files.

Comment: @istruble: well, multipart only works for 5BM+ chunks. But still, I can only test on a few files and hope that the amazon part is free of any bug and that my tests were exhaustive.

Comment: Thank you.  I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to compute a SHA-1 hash on a data stream ([see this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495994/can-sha-1-algorithm-be-computed-on-a-stream-with-low-memory-footprint) for C++ code, which could give hints for a python approach). By redirecting your hashed data stream to the equivalent of `/dev/null`, you should be able to compare SHA-1 hashes of two files without first downloading them locally.

Comment: You're just downloading data to calculate a hash, but not storing the data. As far as any given program is concerned, S3 is just another data source, accessed via web requests.

Comment: I see, it's time to try EC2 :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want without knowing how AWS calculates the etag on multipart uploads. If you have a local copy of the object, you can calculate the md5 of each part that you are copying on the local object and compare it to the etag in the key that each mp.copy_part_from_key() returns. Sounds like you have no local object though.

You also have a small non-obvious problem hiding in boto that may or may not cause you to lose data in a very rare case. If you look at the boto source code, you'll notice that mp.complete_upload() function actually doesn't use any of the etags for any of the parts returned by AWS when uploading. When you use multipart_complete, it actually does a totally new multipart list itself and gets a new list of parts and etags from S3. This is risky because of eventual consistency and the list may or may not be complete. The multipart_complete() should ideally use the etags and part info that was returned by each remote copy to be completely safe. This is what Amazon recommends in its documentation (See the Note under [Multipart Upload Listings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html)).

That said, it's less likely a problem if you confirm the file size of both objects to be the same. The worst case I believe is that a part is not listed in the multipart upload listing. A listed part should never be incorrect itself.