# Generate a sha1 hash from a stream continually in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, hash, stream, cryptography, sha1

I'd like to generate a SHA1 hash continually from a stream that is updated as data is read from the stream.

**What I need, but won't work:**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

hash.update('abc');
console.log(hash.digest('hex')); // hash of abc
hash.update('def');
console.log(hash.digest('hex')); // hash of abcdef
```

This won't work since once hash.digest() is called, you cannot call hash.update() again.

**How can I get the hash for the string each time a chunk is added?**
... without loading the whole string in memory.
... without writing the whole string to the hash again but instead reusing the already written chunks plus the new chunk.

All the examples from the Node.js docs requires the stream to end before the SHA1 is calculated. Once this occurs you cannot write data into the stream anymore.

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

hash.on('readable', () => {
  const data = hash.read();
  if (data) {
    console.log(data.toString('hex'));
    // Prints:
    //   6a2da20943931e9834fc12cfe5bb47bbd9ae43489a30726962b576f4e3993e50
  }
});

hash.write('some data to hash');
hash.end();
```

I would like:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

hash.on('readable', () => {
  const data = hash.read();
  if (data) {
    console.log(data.toString('hex'));
  }
});

hash.write('abc'); // generate hash of "abc"
hash.write('def');
hash.end(); // generate hash of "abcdef"
```

According to this answer you can compute sha1 in blocks.

[Can SHA-1 algorithm be computed on a stream? With low memory footprint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495994/can-sha-1-algorithm-be-computed-on-a-stream-with-low-memory-footprint#2496050)

So you should be able to reuse the calculation from the previous chunks in the stream without having to recalculate as a whole?

The pseudo code from wikipedia shows processing in 512 bit chunks

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

```
Note 1: All variables are unsigned 32-bit quantities and wrap modulo 232 when calculating, except for
        ml, the message length, which is a 64-bit quantity, and
        hh, the message digest, which is a 160-bit quantity.
Note 2: All constants in this pseudo code are in big endian.
        Within each word, the most significant byte is stored in the leftmost byte position

Initialize variables:

h0 = 0x67452301
h1 = 0xEFCDAB89
h2 = 0x98BADCFE
h3 = 0x10325476
h4 = 0xC3D2E1F0

ml = message length in bits (always a multiple of the number of bits in a character).

Pre-processing:
append the bit '1' to the message e.g. by adding 0x80 if message length is a multiple of 8 bits.
append 0 ≤ k < 512 bits '0', such that the resulting message length in bits
   is congruent to −64 ≡ 448 (mod 512)
append ml, the original message length, as a 64-bit big-endian integer. Thus, the total length is a multiple of 512 bits.

Process the message in successive 512-bit chunks:
break message into 512-bit chunks
for each chunk
    break chunk into sixteen 32-bit big-endian words w[i], 0 ≤ i ≤ 15

    Extend the sixteen 32-bit words into eighty 32-bit words:
    for i from 16 to 79
        w[i] = (w[i-3] xor w[i-8] xor w[i-14] xor w[i-16]) leftrotate 1

    Initialize hash value for this chunk:
    a = h0
    b = h1
    c = h2
    d = h3
    e = h4

    Main loop:[3][54]
    for i from 0 to 79
        if 0 ≤ i ≤ 19 then
            f = (b and c) or ((not b) and d)
            k = 0x5A827999
        else if 20 ≤ i ≤ 39
            f = b xor c xor d
            k = 0x6ED9EBA1
        else if 40 ≤ i ≤ 59
            f = (b and c) or (b and d) or (c and d) 
            k = 0x8F1BBCDC
        else if 60 ≤ i ≤ 79
            f = b xor c xor d
            k = 0xCA62C1D6

        temp = (a leftrotate 5) + f + e + k + w[i]
        e = d
        d = c
        c = b leftrotate 30
        b = a
        a = temp

    Add this chunk's hash to result so far:
    h0 = h0 + a
    h1 = h1 + b 
    h2 = h2 + c
    h3 = h3 + d
    h4 = h4 + e

Produce the final hash value (big-endian) as a 160-bit number:
hh = (h0 leftshift 128) or (h1 leftshift 96) or (h2 leftshift 64) or (h3 leftshift 32) or h4
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a question here.

Comment: I edited it. Is that clearer? @JamesKPolk

Comment: I'm no javascript expert, but it does not seem like the node.js hash class supports the functionality you want. [This](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/sha1.js.html) seems to do it, if you use what looks like a copy constructor (whatever you call it in javascript).